# How to find array / dictionary value using key?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I would like to find the value in an array using the key.

Like this:

```
$array=('us'=>'United', 'ca'=>'canada');
$key='ca';
```

How can I have the value 'canada'?

Comment: What language?  I see one answer that appears to be assuming Perl, and one that's assuming PHP.

Comment: If it is PHP you might want to read: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: Yes, it's PHP.
Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 112):

It's as simple as this :

```
$array[$key];
```

Answer (score 33):

It looks like you're writing PHP, in which case you want:

```
<?
$arr=array('us'=>'United', 'ca'=>'canada');
$key='ca';
echo $arr[$key];
?>
```

Notice that the `('us'=>'United', 'ca'=>'canada')` needs to be a parameter to the [array function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP.

Most programming languages that support associative arrays or dictionaries use `arr['key']` to retrieve the item specified by `'key'`

For instance:

#### Ruby

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > h = {'us' => 'USA', 'ca' => 'Canada' }
 => {"us"=>"USA", "ca"=>"Canada"} 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > h['ca']
 => "Canada"
```

#### Python

```
>>> h = {'us':'USA', 'ca':'Canada'}
>>> h['ca']
'Canada'
```

#### C`#`

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var d = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> { {"us", "USA"}, {"ca", "Canada"}};
        System.Console.WriteLine(d["ca"]);
    }
}
```

#### Lua

```
t = {us='USA', ca='Canada'}
print(t['ca'])
print(t.ca) -- Lua's a little different with tables
```