# how to get array that starts with specific key

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel

I have a array like this

```
   array:33 [▼
  10 => array:3 [▶]
  136 => array:3 [▶]
  137 => array:3 [▶]
  138 => array:3 [▶]
  "new-31" => array:3 [▶]
  "new-32" => array:3 [▶]
  "new-33" => array:3 [▶]
]
```

how can I access to only array that starts with new-*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find array value using key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970768/find-array-value-using-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it using `foreach` loop like below

```
foreach($yourarray as $key => $your){
    if(strpos($key, 'new') !== false){
        // Here you can access the elements which starts from the "new"
    }
}
```