# How to convert a string to point to a value in an array

Tags: php

I have a dynamically generated array. It is an associative array containing one or more sub-arrays. I also have a variable that dynamically generates a string value that should match an address within that array. How can use that string to retrieve the value at the corresponding address within the array? eg

```
<?php
$array = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'x' => 0, 'y' => 'seven', 'tuppence' => [ 'price' =>'thruppence' ]];
$string = "$array['foo']";
$value = $string;
```

In this particular instance $value should = 'bar'. but it currently has the value "$array['foo']". The value of $string is dynamically generated, so on other occasions $string may = "$array['x']", in which case, $value should = 0; not "$array['x']"

I have tried making the string a reference, ie:

```
$value = &$string;
```

or including braces, eg:

```
$string = "{$array}['foo']";
```

or

```
$string = "($array['foo']}";
```

but nothing seems to work, by which I mean that PHP still treats $string as a string of meaningless text, rather than a reference pointing to an actual value at the corresponding address within an existing array, ie

```
print_r( $array);
```

produces a print out of the array.

In summary, I am asking: how do I change the expression:

```
$value = $string;
```

to make $value actually become the value at the corresponding address within $array?

Comment: No need to quote the `$string` assignment; `$string = $array['foo'];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find array value using key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970768/find-array-value-using-key)

Comment: I think you need to better explain your question. What is the source of `$string`? Otherwise you will continue to get answers which (to my reading of the question) don't answer it at all.

Comment: You especially need to clarify: "I have a string that matches an address within that array.", because it seems like you don't have it, but are rather trying to create it. If you indeed have a string value, can you give an example of its contents?

Answer (score 1):

use curly brackets as such  "{$arr['key']}"

```
$array = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];
$string = "{$array['foo']}";
$value = $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working?

```
$array = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];
$string = &$array['foo'];
```

String must be the address of the array key