# Yii2 search array and find the matching value

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have created an array

```
  $myArray =    [
        'JAN' => '01',
        'jan' => '01',
        'FEB' => '02',
        'feb' => '02',
        'MAR' => '03',
        'mar' => '03',
        'APR' => '04',
        'apr' => '04',
        'MAY' => '05',
        'may' => '05',
        'JUNE' => '06',
        'june' => '06',
        'JUL' => '07',
        'jul' => '07',
        'AUG' => '08',
        'aug' => '08',
        'SEPT' => '09',
        'sept' => '09',
        'OCT' => '10',
        'oct' => '10',
        'NOV' => '11',
        'nov' => '11',
        'DEC' => '12',
        'dec' => '12',

    ];
```

The above array is inside my function. This function accepts a string. The string is the short form of a month and it can be any of the months in a year. So I want to search my input variable with the array provided that if it matched any of the given elements then it will return the month number.

How can I do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find array / dictionary value using key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970768/how-to-find-array-dictionary-value-using-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give another answer to this, you can just use the `date` functions, for example;

```
$month_name = "march"; // or MARCH (case doesn't matter)
$month_number = date("m", strtotime($month_name));
echo $month_number; // echos 03
```

You can also use short names for this, for example;

```
$month_name = "mar"; // or MAR (case doesn't matter)
$month_number = date("m", strtotime($month_name));
echo $month_number; // echos 03
```

This greatly reduces your need for arrays and dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can omit lowercase or uppercase letters from your array and cast given key to lower/uppercase letters. For example drop lowercase values and your array will look like this

```
$myArray =    [
    'JAN' => '01',
    'FEB' => '02',
    'MAR' => '03',
    'APR' => '04',
    'MAY' => '05',
    'JUNE' => '06',
    'JUL' => '07',
    'AUG' => '08',
    'SEPT' => '09',
    'OCT' => '10',
    'NOV' => '11',
    'DEC' => '12'

];
```

to get value from array use strtoupper()

```
 $key = 'mar';
 $month = $myarray[strtoupper($key)]; // $month = '03'
```